# Windows Authentication on IIS and WEB API very slowly

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have performance issue with configuration of WEB API on IIS 10.

Part routes are for anonymous allowed and have response time of 1 sec (as comparative value). Other routes are only for windows authentication alowed and are very slow (3,5 sec).

Client and server are in same AD, everything seems ok configured and Kerberos tickets seems to be there.

With series query, first request takes twice as Long (no matter with or without windows authentication).

What can that be?

Response times of 3,5 seconds are really to slow!

PS. Tried and read a lot ... no success :-/

Big thanks!

Comment: Ask your domain administrators to help, and use tools like Wireshark to confirm how much time is used for every steps of authentication.

Comment: First, please use some performance profiler and failed request tracing to narrow down the low performance part. If it is proved that the windows authentication get slow, then you can trace the kerberos authentication via network monitor.  Besides, have you tried to set  authPersistNonNTLM=true?

Comment: @JokiesDing - Yes … I set authPersistNonNTLM to true.

Comment: @LexLi - I was hoping to find the answers / suggestions here. :-/

Comment: That's my suggestion. Windows authentication is too complex to troubleshoot, and you won't be able to share your environment with anyone over the internet.